# Explain verses 25:3 and 16:21

Tags: quran

In 25:3 it is said:

> Yet they have taken besides Him gods who cannot create anything but
> are themselves created. Nor can they protect or benefit themselves.
> Nor can they control life, death, or resurrection.25:3

Explain the verse because angels take the soul and therefore have power over death.  According to 4:97:

> When the angels seize the souls of those who have wronged
> themselves1—scolding them, “What do you think you were doing?” they
> will reply, “We were oppressed in the land.” The angels will respond,
> “Was Allah’s earth not spacious enough for you to emigrate?” It is
> they who will have Hell as their home—what an evil destination!4:97

And also: specify the moment at 16:21

> They are dead, not alive—not even knowing when their followers will be
> resurrected.16:21

The polytheists also worshipped angels, and they are alive.

Comment: Couldn't a human also say he has power over death with this logic, like the king in the story of Ibrahim (AS) did? (Quran 2:258)

Answer (score 1):

Please ask one question at a time!

The assumption **angels take the soul and therefore have power over death** is wrong because angels don't move an inch or descends without the commandment of Allah.
They don't have the knowledge of when a person is going to die nor they have power to kill anyone without Allah's will they only descend by Order of Allah.

Referring to [19:64]

> “We only descend by the command of your Lord. To Him belongs whatever is before us, and whatever is behind us, and everything in between. And your Lord is never forgetful.

**[19:64]** is also a reply to those who think/thought that Angels listen to their supplication and can benefit them.

For [16:21]:-

The idols/deities were deceased prophets, saints, pious and other extraordinary beings buried in their graves and not angels, jinns, devils or idols. For the angels and devils are alive: therefore, the words, “They are dead, not living” cannot apply to them. Here angels are excluded because they are alive, living.

[Tafsir Of 16:21](https://myislam.org/surah-nahl/ayat-21/)